# How to auto-increment ID in Batch insert

Tags: mysql, batch-insert

I have the following query that I want to execute

```
INSERT INTO TableB (ID, Age, RollNo)
SELECT (select (max(id) + 1) from TableB), Age, RollNo
FROM TableA
WHERE Age > 20 AND RollNo < 500
```

Now all the new entries have the same ID in the TableB

Am i doing something wrong.

P.S. I cannot change the column properties, I cannot set it to AUTO-INCREMENT, it needs to have default value NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the `ID` column in `TableB` as `AUTO_INCREMENT` which will eventually serve this purpose

```
ALTER TABLE TableB MODIFY COLUMN ID INT auto_increment
```

In that case you can generate those numbers like

```
SET @id := (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM TableB);

INSERT INTO TableB (ID, Age, RollNo)
SELECT (@id := @id + 1), Age, RollNo
FROM TableA
WHERE Age > 20 AND RollNo < 500;
```

Comment: P.S. I cannot change the column properties, I cannot set it to AUTO-INCREMENT, it needs to have default value NULL

Comment: you are a genius my friend. Thanks a lot.